# Search Widgets' title on ELGG 1.8

Tags: php, search, widget, customization, elgg

I'm developing a social portal with ELGG 1.8 and I'm having some trouble with ELGG's default search engine.

What I want to do:
I need widgets' titles to be included in the search engine process/result list and they aren't by default. I don't know how to enable it.

What I achieved:
Now in search results widgets' descriptions are listed, but no titles yet.

Can someone suggest me something about how to solve this? I already read ELGG documentations from http://docs.elgg.org but I didn't find anything usefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Widgets are entites in Elgg. But they differ in such a way that they lack title and description. Your solution is to create a hook for the widget creation event and add title and description and add widget entities to search function. (it needs some major coding)

I am not getting how you are searching widgets based on descriptions?
The better place to ask these types of questions is Elgg community itself.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I'll do that.